# Ruby - rSpecs for XML API - Integration Test

Tags: ruby, xml, rspec, integration-testing

I have been writing a ruby library to interact with the Eve Online API.  It is a fairly straight forward API that fires back XML and accepts a API Key and Token.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction on how to write tests in rSpec for an XML API and what the best way to mock the API is.

Thanks

Comment: Please supply code up the point you are stuck (simplify it, no need to repeat etc). Otherwise it is hard to tell what is blocking you, and it is too much to write a general introduction to testing XML over HTTP using rspec. Have you worked through any rspec tutorials already?

Comment: In general, you don't want to mock code you don't own; in this case, a third party library.  It's brittle, you can't respond to design pressures, etc.  See "Growing Object Oriented Software, Guided by Tests" by Freeman & Pryce.